# My web pages are not refreshed in my php web application

Tags: html, web, refresh

My web pages are not refreshed after editing my web page in PHP, still old contents are showing. Many times refreshed it but not refreshed. whenever I delete history, it is refreshed. How could my clients see the edited contents when they take webpage very first time itself, just like everyday newspaper, we are seeing new contents each day without clicking refresh button?

Comment: Check line 38 in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given enough information for us to really understand what is going on.
From my understanding your problem is that you are changing something on your website and even though you refresh. Nothing is changing.
This could be cache-related, press CTRL+SHIFT+R to delete the cache(this does not harm your website).
Cache is a temporary storage, maybe the current web view is grabbing information from the cache instead of from the live code(very usual).

Comment: Thank you. Can I suggest my client to do this always? one more doubt, whenever I read the newspaper, i never ever see old contents. What they are doing in their code to refresh automatically.

Comment: It really depends on what you are changing, cache will always be a thing. However you can implement AJAX(javascript code,(way of inserting/updating database records etc) to your project. AJAX removes the having to refresh. This changes automatically.
You also have some Javascript frameworks which give the possibility to do so.

I don't know of any different way apart from these libraries/frameworks/code method.
On certain CMS (like MODX) you can let your website always load with cache or never load with cache. It really depends on your situation. 

I hope this helps you.

Comment: In my case static contents(html) are not changing. But dynamic contents are changing means from the database.

Comment: @AnuAlex Are you sure you are working inside of the correct file?
Also are you working locally or are you sending your files to an online website with an FTP connection? Maybe there is something wrong with the connection to the FTP server.

Try explaining more about what you are trying to do and what the result of those actions are. It would help out a lot.